# return a list without its last element

Tags: ocaml

I need to return a list deprived of its last element, for example a `string list` like `["one" ; "two" ; "three"]` must display `["one" ; "two"]`, only with predefined functions `List.hd`, `List.tl` or `List.length`.

What I did, doesn't work at all :

```
let rec remove_last l =
    match l with
    | [] -> []
    | head :: tail when n = 0 -> tail
    | head :: tail -> head :: (remove (n - 1) tail);;

remove_last l ["one" ; "two" ; "three"];;
```

Comment: Note that when you _call_ `remove_last` the name `l` is unbound. This will definitely give you an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type

```
let rec remove_last l = 
   match l with 
   | [] -> [] 
   | [_] -> [] 
   | hd::tl -> hd::(remove_last tl);;
```

This can be converted without match, but following the same logic:

```
let rec remove_last l =
  if l = [] then [] else
  if List.tl l = [] then [] else
  List.hd l :: remove_last (List.tl l);;
```

Comment: Note that `| [] -> [] | [_] -> []` can be `| [] | [_] -> []`

Answer (score 2):

You say you need a solution *with* List.hd, List.tl, List.length. But I'm pretty sure you need a solution *without* these built-in functions. This is the usual requirement, as it means you have to work with the basic language features (pattern matching and recursion).

Your code uses a function named `remove` and a variable named `n` but there's no function `remove` or variable `n` defined anywhere. So it's reasonable that your code wouldn't work.

One way to solve the problem would be to use the length of the list, but then you need to calculate the length of the list without using `List.length`.

It seems to me that rather than defining your own length function, you might just as well use patterns and recursion to solve the problem directly. The end of the list will be a pattern like this `[_]`, where `_` matches the last element of the list. If you see this pattern the resulting list should be empty `[]`, i.e., the last element is removed.

If you think recursively, you can see that the base cases are a list of length 0 (which you are handling correctly in your code) or of length 1 (handled as described above). Any other list can be handled recursively by prefixing the head of the list to the shortened version of the tail of the list.

I hope this helps. I don't want to write code for you because this is an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using just pattern-matching, then you can think directly in terms of what would a particular pattern result in:

- If we're given an empty list, presumably an exception would be raised.
- If a single element, an empty list.
- If you have more than two or more elements, it would presumably be the first element tacked onto the result of removing the last element from the tail of the list.

Now, if you must only use `List.hd`, `List.tl`, and `List.length`, you can accomplish this by first calculating the length of the original list, and then defining an auxiliary function which keeps track of indices and only collects elements from the original list while the index is less than the length minus one.

The basic form of that function might look like the following.

```
let remove_last lst =
  let len = ... in
  let rec aux i lst =
    if i < len - 1 then ...
    else ...
  in
  aux ... lst
```